# If a comma were to be put before "when", does it change the meaning?

Tags: punctuation, commas

> "So what happened to you two?" said Harry. 
>  "Well, I got back all
>   right," said Hermione. "I brought Ron round - that took a while - and
>   we were dashing up to the owlery to contact Dumbledore **when** we met
>   him in the entrance hall - he already knew - he just said, 'Harry's
>   gone after him, hasn't he?' and hurtled off to the third floor."
>   (Harry Potter)

If a comma were to be put before *when*, does it change the meaning?

Comment: I think not. It would change the 'reading' - the phrasing, and an actor playing the part would have to adjust her internal sense of the rhythm.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this particular sentence, it would be possible to add the comma, but it wouldn't change the meaning. It's probably a bad idea anyway, because a comma "slows down" the reading - so it would conflict with the sense of "rushed speech" that we get from the context (and the hyphens!)

But in a slightly different sentence:

> *We were discussing what to say to Dumbledore, when he walked in the room.*
>    **with the comma**, there's a pause which tells us how to interpret the "when" clause.
>    Dumbledore walked in the room just at the time we were discussing what we would say to him.
>
> *We were discussing what to say to Dumbledore when he walked in the room.*
>    **without the comma**, we assume "when" applies to what came before, not what comes after.
>    We expected Dumbledore to walk in soon; we were discussing what we would say if/when he did.

So a comma before "when" *can* make a difference. It just so happens it doesn't in OP's example.